# Can we set any number of Redirect URI in a application for multiple users?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

I am working on a multitenant application where we will have multiple base urls based on our customers.
Here I have a requirement to set Redirect URI for each customers. My confusion is can we set any number of uri in an application? Or Is there any limitation or maximum limit of creating the uri?
This application is created as microservice.

Comment: Where do you want to set those? Generally speaking, "inifinite" is  out of reach, but based on your architecture and memory available, you can probably save quiet a few strings in a collection.

Comment: I have changed the title

Comment: I need to set this in the launchsettings.json file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right, maybe an example would be beneficial.

In general, you can use path parameters to make an URI customer-specific, e.g. `/pre-path/customer/{customerId}/redirect`. This is basically one path, but `customerId` is used as parameter to distinguish multiple users and can have "infinite" different values.